# how to compile C++ - libsndfile on iOS

Tags: c++, xcode, libsndfile

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/vibhavarirajadnya/MyDev/iOS-Projects/Music/POC/ReadWaveFile/ReadWaveFile/libsndfile.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/vibhavarirajadnya/MyDev/iOS-Projects/Music/POC/ReadWaveFile/ReadWaveFile/libsndfile.a
>   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_sf_close", referenced from:
>         SndfileHandle::SNDFILE_ref::~SNDFILE_ref() in ReadWaveFile.o
>     "_sf_open", referenced from:
>         SndfileHandle::SndfileHandle(char const*, int, int, int, int) in ReadWaveFile.o
>     "_sf_strerror", referenced from:
>         SndfileHandle::strError() const in ReadWaveFile.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried compiling libsndfile file in 3 ways:
1. ./configure then make and make install through command prompt. 
2. http://ofdsp.blogspot.in/2011/07/installing-libsndfile-with-xcode.html
3. http://en.efreedom.net/Question/1-11576168/Cross-Compile-Libsndfile-Arm-Raspberry-Pi

With the first option I am getting the error mentioned above. With the second, I am getting some 69 errors most of them related to FLAC. With the third option I am getting the same as 1. It also gives a msg in the command prompt:
Installation directories :

```
Library directory : ................... /Users/vibhavarirajadnya/Arm/lib
Program directory : ................... /Users/vibhavarirajadnya/Arm/bin
Pkgconfig directory : ................. /Users/vibhavarirajadnya/Arm/lib/pkgconfig
HTML docs directory : ................. /Users/vibhavarirajadnya/Arm/share/doc/libsndfile1-dev/html
```

But when I check in Finder, there is no such directory.

Can somebody tell me a step by step method to compile libsndfile and its dependencies for Mac iOSX?

Comment: The error message is telling you you're trying to link a library built for a different architecture than the one you're using. Apparently you're targetting MacOS (i386) but your lib has been compiled for another architecture. You probably haven't correctly specified the architecture when doing the `./configure`.

Comment: the third option says use this: ./configure --prefix=$HOME/Arm --build=i386-linux --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi. But didn't work out. I am relatively new to iOS apps. Any help would be appreciated.